# Python3.7 is not compatible with Tensorflow?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I am trying to continue with a Rasa chatbot that I have not used since September and I find a syntax problem with the dependency of Tensorflow. I do not know if this is due to the fact that there are [updates to be made with my dependencies](https://rasa.com/docs/core/migrations/) or if it [due to the fact that I use python3.7 as suggested by people on GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20690), or some other reason.

```
(moo_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\projects\moodbot>py train_online.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_online.py", line 37, in <module>
    nlu_interpreter = RasaNLUInterpreter('./models/nlu/default/moodnlu')
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\projects\moodbot\moo_env\lib\site-packages\rasa_core\interpreter.py", line 221, in __init__
    self._load_interpreter()
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\projects\moodbot\moo_env\lib\site-packages\rasa_core\interpreter.py", line 237, in _load_interpreter
    self.interpreter = Interpreter.load(self.model_directory)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\projects\moodbot\moo_env\lib\site-packages\rasa_nlu\model.py", line 276, in load
    skip_validation)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\projects\moodbot\moo_env\lib\site-packages\rasa_nlu\model.py", line 298, in create
    components.validate_requirements(model_metadata.component_classes)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\projects\moodbot\moo_env\lib\site-packages\rasa_nlu\components.py", line 49, in validate_requirements
    from rasa_nlu import registry
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\projects\moodbot\moo_env\lib\site-packages\rasa_nlu\registry.py", line 23, in <module>
    from rasa_nlu.classifiers.embedding_intent_classifier import \
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\projects\moodbot\moo_env\lib\site-packages\rasa_nlu\classifiers\embedding_intent_classifier.py", line 32, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\projects\moodbot\moo_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\projects\moodbot\moo_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\projects\moodbot\moo_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\projects\moodbot\moo_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 114
    def TFE_ContextOptionsSetAsync(arg1, async):

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

You can find my code in [Github repository](https://github.com/antoinecomp/moodbot)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is this line in `pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py`:

```
def TFE_ContextOptionsSetAsync(arg1, async):
```

Since Python 3.5, `async` (and `await`) are keywords and can no longer be used as identifiers. I assume you use a very outdated version of tensorflow.

Comment: Thanks for your insights! I thought I had a pretty new version and I updated in any case with `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow` but I still have the same error :/

Comment: @ThePassenger What does `python3 -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'` print?

Comment: The same error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` on `def TFE_ContextOptionsSetAsync(arg1, async):`

Comment: Try completely removing tensorflow, _then try importing it despite your uninstallation_. Do you still get the same error, or an ImportError? If all else fails, edit that file to rename the `async` parameter to something else.

Comment: A `ModuleNotFoundError`. Maybe I should add that I use `py` rather than `python3` in the command line.